# Multiple Join Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

HEllo guys please i have this problem have been trying to solve,
am building a soccer prediction app,and i have all my teams in a
table(teams) which has 3 columns(team_id,name,logo)once a a person 
predicts a game prediction table looks like dis(Home_team id,aw
away_team_id,user_prediction) Home_team_id and away_team_id 
both refrences team_id on team table. Pls how do i get the 
user prediction to show both team names. I.e(if i predict
arsenal vs chelsea game prediction table will show(1,3,1);
how do i show a user the real names i.e(Arsenal,Chelsea,Arsenal).instead of the foreign keys.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name, t3.user_prediction
FROM predictions AS t3
JOIN teams as t1 on (t3.home_team_id = t1.team_id)
JOIN teams as t2 on (t3.away_team_id = t2.team_id);
```

Haven't tested, but it will look something like that.

Comment: fields `predictions` on joins -> `t3` and you'll probably need to specify a join type

Comment: yeah `predictions` can be specified as `t3`, and join type is `INNER JOIN` which is the same as not mentioning any join.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your response,i'd try it out now